# php undefined variable after unset

Tags: php

I have a list of string in a loop and i am trying to remove strings bigger than 3 letters long, so that I can keep the full words and remove the short hands.

```
    string(2) "en"
    string(7) "English"
    string(7) "English"
    string(2) "en"
    string(3) "eng"
    string(2) "en"
    string(2) "fr"
    string(6) "French"
    string(6) "French"
    string(2) "fr"
    string(3) "fra"
    string(2) "fr"
    string(2) "es"
    string(7) "Spanish"
    string(7) "Spanish"
    string(2) "es"
    string(3) "spa"
    string(2) "es"
    string(2) "ja"
    string(8) "Japanese"
    string(8) "Japanese"
    string(2) "ja"
    string(3) "jpn"
    string(2) "ja"
    string(2) "fr"
    string(6) "French"
    string(6) "French"
    string(2) "fr"
```

When I run the below php code, I got the error
`undefined variable` at var_dump.

I have tried with below php code :

```
    foreach ($subtitles as $subtitle) {
        foreach (array_unique($subtitle->get('language')) as $lan) {
            if (strlen($lan) > 3) {
                unset($lan);

            }
            var_dump($lan);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you have unset `$lan`, you can't do anything with it (it in effect doesn't exist).  But in your loop, you don't actually do anything with the data.

This uses `array_filter()` to filter out anything over 3 chars...

```
$out = array_filter(array_unique($subtitle->get('language')),
        function ($lan) { return strlen($lan) <= 3; });
print_r($out);
```

Answer (score 0):

fixed by adding `continue;`

```
foreach ($subtitles as $subtitle) {
    foreach (array_unique($subtitle->get('language')) as $lan) {
        if (strlen($lan) > 3) {
            unset($lan);
            continue;
        }
        var_dump($lan);
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the unset?  It doesn't make much sense to unset the subject of a foreach loop.